# IIFE or let, when use js variable

Tags: javascript

As the title suggests,
I'd like to ask a question about JavaScript writing style.
Assuming variable "a" is known, it won't change in the future.
Which of the following two approaches is better?

```
let a 
if(someCondition){
  a=2
}else{
  a=3
}
```

```
const a = (()=>{
  if(someCondition){
    return 2
  }else{
    return 3
  }
})()
```

Comment: Whichever you like more, I guess. There's no style that is objectively better. Whichever works for you.

Comment: Both are fine. You could also write it as a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator) `const a = someCondition ? 2 : 3;`

Comment: Trick question: neither. If the condition is this simple, use a conditional operator. If it's sufficiently complex to avoid the conditional operator, create a separate function.

Comment: I think you can say that the first solution is worse, without being opinionated. You want the variable to be not changeable. So using the `let` operator is the wrong choice. Whether the second solution is the best solution out there is another question.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion ruling is simple: use `const` everywhere.

If mutation is needed, use **another variable** to store the changed version. Read topics about **immutability** and **functional programming**, to learn related useful techniques.

Your example specifically would be:

```js
const a = someCondition ? 2 : 3;
```

And if something is more complex, than IIFE is ok, but I would always try to use sequence of `if->return`s, than using `switch-case->return`s` (but this is subjective).